# Firebase Limiting User Password Reset Limit, How Can I Reset?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Note: I'm on the Blaze Plan

I have a firebase auth user that just set up a paid account, and they're receiving a `RESET_PASSWORD_EXCEED_LIMIT` yet my other paid accounts aren't. How do I reset this user's password? I'm not sure what the individual reset limit is, I couldn't find it in the docs.

I have 110 users which I've gained over 48 hours

*Failed Solution*: I re-created the account, but the new account, even though it was able to generate email password resets, it actually was a link that didn't work, leading me to believe it's a bug. The user had to create a new account with a new email.

Comment: Check Auth Limit here : https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/limits

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour That actually doesn't have limits for specific user emails, it only says "global" emails

Comment: Yes .. I know .. I just wanted to help you out .. I gived you the link for help :)

Comment: This sounds like an undocumented quota limitation.  Your best bet is probably contacting Firebase support directly

Comment: @touchmybody I agree, I'm going to reach out to them next week, it's only happened to one user out of 160 so far. BTW Your name is pretty funny haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**From Firebase Support**

> An OOB link is the link generated for the reset password email, it
> contains an oobcode which is a one-time code, used to identify and
> verify a request. Saying this, each user is permitted to use a certain
> amount of links, then if he exceeds  the internal quota, the error
> message “RESET_PASSWORD_EXCEED_LIMIT” will appear.
>
> To reset the quota, you just need to click the link and reset the
> password, this workaround is not good for a real user, but if you are
> testing it can help you to reset the quota. The real workaround for a
> real user would be to wait for a period of time until the OOB links
> naturally expire.
>
> To avoid hitting this quota, I recommend you to add a validation in
> your UI of the number of retries that the user can request a
> reset-email password email. For example, setting a restriction of four
> requests maximum in ten minutes would avoid triggering our alerting
> system. This is not the exact quota, but I am giving you a good limit
> that you can set in your application.

Comment: I was developing a Cloud Function and was generating codes with the Firebase Admin SDK: `admin.auth().generatePasswordResetLink('user@example.com').then(createPasswordUrl => console.log(createPasswordUrl))`. That meant I wasn't clicking on them. I eventually got the `RESET_PASSWORD_EXCEED_LIMIT` error. I copied and pasted one of the links into a browser and that reset the quota and allowed me to start generating them again.

Comment: @anothermh that is an excelelnt thing to note! I appreciate that